# JSON Deserializing in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, serialization

I have a json string like this

```
"{"value":"{\"success\":false,\"htmlCode\":\"Exists\",\"key\":\"xxxxxxxx-yyyy-zzzz-aaaa-bbbbbbbbbbbb\"}"}"
```

I'm trying to deseriazlie this in javascript using following logic and trying to access one of the values in it.

```
obj = JSON.parse(data);
alert(obj.success);
```

But it fails all the time. I also tried doing

```
alert(obj.value.htmlCode);
alert(obj["value"].htmlCode);
alert(obj.value["htmlCode"]);
```

but nothing worked.

Can someone help please?

Comment: *it fails* - *nothing worked* What error do you get ?

Comment: `obj.value` is JSON-encoded string. So you have to apply `JSON.parse` to it.

Comment: You're string is not written properly. Not all double quotes are escaped which mean essentially as far as JS is concerned that's few strings and some undefined references.

Comment: Fix your JSON: don't double encode it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Please Remove Value From the JSON code**

below is the updated JSON string
'{\"success\":false,\"htmlCode\":\"Exists\",\"key\":\"xxxxxxxx-yyyy-zzzz-aaaa-bbbbbbbbbbbb\"}';

It will surely resolve your issue

Answer (score -1):

Just make sure you escaped everything :

```js
var value = "{\"value\":{\"success\":false,\"htmlCode\":\"Exists\",\"key\":\"xxxxxxxx-yyyy-zzzz-aaaa-bbbbbbbbbbbb\"}}";

console.log(JSON.parse(value));
```

Hope it helps